# Chrome: show DNS resolve time and other network timings

Tags: google-chrome, networking, dns

When you install the dev version of Chrome (on linux) there is a light grey box in the bottom left corner of the screen that shows when the DNS is being resolved, page is loading etc and is useful debugging information without having to pull up the network tab of the developer console.

Is there an option in non dev builds of Chrome to turn this on?

Comment: To the person who has voted for close, please explain how this is not a question about "software tools commonly used by programmers" thanks  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 8):

Try navigating to:

```
chrome://net-internals/#dns
```

Information about cache hits is available at:

```
chrome://dns/
```

To list all available pages:

```
chrome://chrome-urls/
```

Comment: Really interesting and useful links, thanks!  Is not exactly the outcome I was looking for though as I want to see Chrome's network status being displayed in that grey box in the bottom left of the screen without having the over head of de-cyphering the internals of Chrome DNS / network logging.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: If you can't find this info anywhere, I suppose your best bet is asking on #chromium @ Freenode. I doubt such thing exists out of the box though.